# Eventos con mysql (borrado por comparación)

Tags: mysql, date, eventos

Actualmente tengo una base de datos con unas cuantas rows, una de ellas contiene la data la cual tiene de ser borrado el documento en formato time stamp (Y-m-j H:i:s) estoy creando un evento el cual pase la data/fecha del borrado, el registro sea borrado mi pregunta es ¿como seria el delete?

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE EVENT registros
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 MINUTE 
    DO
    BEGIN
      DELETE FROM DOCUMENTOS WHERE tiempo < date ('Y-m-j H:i:s',now())
    END $$
DELIMITER ;
```